# Outlook security prompt: Sendkeys does not have the right focus

Tags: vba, outlook, sendkeys

I want to automate some basic operations in Outlook 2014, so I create a macro in VBA. But I need to send an email if any error occur during the execution of the script, and I want to bypass the confirmation message of Outlook (the pop up which appeared when you want to send a mail with a macro).

```
Private Sub sendEmailError()
  Dim Email As Outlook.Application
  Dim EmailMsg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim Dest As Outlook.Recipient

  Set Email = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set EmailMsg = Email.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  Set Dest = EmailMsg.Recipients.Add("mail@mail.com")

  EmailMsg.Subject = MessageSubject
  EmailMsg.Body = MessageBody
  EmailMsg.Display
  SendKeys "^{ENTER}", True
End Sub
```

I thought "EmailMsg.Display" would give the focus to the message box and then, thanks to the sendkeys, I could execute the shortcut to send the email. But the focus is not given to the message box, and the control+key shortcut is done in my script after the end of the macro...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to override the prompt, but kind of by definition you're not supposed to, and my guess is that Microsoft's probably put some security measures to prevent you from doing so. The prompt is meant to make sure that the user is OK with a macro messing with their emails, so it defeats the point to allow macros to just click 'OK' on behalf of the user.

What you can do instead is go into the Outlook Trust Center, and on the Programmatic Access tab, set it to 'Never warn me about suspicious activity'. This will remove the prompt permanently.

Comment: You're right... It's probably not possible... Thank you for yor help!

Answer (score 0):

I know its not what you aks for, but

```
EmailMsg.Send
```

instead of

```
EmailMsg.Display
```

would send it right away

Comment: EmailMsg.Send works perfectly but show the warning message. I would like to do the ame thing that the 4th message in this link : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/614075-send-email-without-warning.html

Comment: Sending Space to accept Warning Message does not work? Focus should be set on the msgbox or not?

Comment: It works but just for the help button and the deny button. For the allow button, it will just select it and wait for a user action.

Answer (score 0):

With the extra warning Message, it will look like this:

```
Private Sub sendEmailError()
  Dim Email As Outlook.Application
  Dim EmailMsg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim Dest As Outlook.Recipient

  Set Email = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set EmailMsg = Email.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  Set Dest = EmailMsg.Recipients.Add("mail@mail.com")

  EmailMsg.Subject = MessageSubject
  EmailMsg.Body = MessageBody
  EmailMsg.Send
  SendKeys " "
End Sub
```

Comment: I test this function right now, and it works only for the help button and the deny button. For the allow button, it will only select it and wait for a user action.

Comment: Will it select the accept button?
Or ask otherwise, if you see the warning and hit space by yourself, does it affect the msgbox?
Unfortunately the prompt is not shown on my system (outlook 2016).

Maybe sending key "y" to select "yes" before sending space? :/

Comment: If I hit myself the space and I'm on the accept button, it will accept, but if it's sendkeys which hits the accept button, it'll not accept it. Thank you for your concern ^^